# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've been facing this attribute error, any ideas how I can solve it?

```
def model(input_shape):
   model = keras.Sequential()
   model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(1,9), return_sequences=True))
   model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64))
   model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
   model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
   model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
   return model

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [67], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
      2 model.summary()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function and variable have the same name, causing the issue. You can either rename the variable or the function.

```py
def model(input_shape):
   model = keras.Sequential()
   model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(1,9), return_sequences=True))
   model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64))

   model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
   model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
   
   model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

   return model

my_model = model() # your initializer
my_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
my_model.summary()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't *have* to rename either of these. `model = model()` is perfectly valid. You just wouldn't be able to call the `model` function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You've used the word `model` as a name for a function. That is permissible (because `model` is not a reserved word in Python), but it means that when you use `model.compile()`, the interpreter assumes you want to call an attribute of what you called "model", and there is no such attribute there.
Solution: Give the function another name so that the word "model" only refers to the model object, which has a `compile` method you can call. Or, conversely, use "model" for the function if you want to, but then give the model another name, and call `compile()` on that.